# domain move but wierd path errors and 'caching' without cache enabled

Tags: admin, error, css, domain

I am trying to create a staging site to debug our site.
I have created it:
 - Disabled compilation.
 - Disabled caching  directly in the db
 - Deleted the `var/cahce/` contents just to be sure.
 - Updated `unsecure_base_url` and `secure_base_url` in the db.

I've also checked the base skin urls etc just to make sure they are correct.

I've disabled ssl in the db to keep things simple.

Changed the database credentials in `local.xml`

Changed the apc prefix to be specific to the staging site.

Disabled the BOLT full page cache we use.

Checked the virtual host setup to make sure it is loading from the right directories.

Yet when I access debug.domain.com two issues happen.
In the frontend the catalog links etc all refer to www.domain.com not debug.domain.com
and when I access the admin and log in none of it renders correctly because all of the resources have the full file path amended so it tries to load 
e.g.
http://debug.domain.com/var/www/vhosts/debug.domain.com/web/content/skin/adminhtml/default/default/lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css

rather than http://debug.domain.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css

I'm totally stumped, I've been through loads of walkthroughs trying to spot something I've missed, can anyone spot anything I've forgotten or suggest anywhere else to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing can happen when you have css/js merging turned on but Magento doesn't have the required permissions to write to the media directory.

As a quick fix you can turn off css merging, alternatively try changing the media directory permissions to allow Magento write permissions. The permissions required will depend on your server, Magento recommends 700 in there [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html), however if that doesn't work you could try something a bit more forgiving like 755.